# Actions events not working after adding row in the second page on DataTables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

So i have a dataTable with actions buttons, it work fine on the first page.
But when i change page, change the number of show entries or search an entrie the events on the entries that where hidden don't work :

Tried this : 
[Datatable event on page change not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979873/datatable-event-on-page-change-not-working?rq=1)
but I can't make it work.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/webolive/vg3wkx0d/28/

Here a simplified version of my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "drawCallback": initRowsEvents(),
  });

  let index = 2;

  function initRowsEvents() {

    $(".hi").unbind().click(function() {
      let name = $(this).parent().prev().text();
      alert('Oh, Hi ' + name + '!');
    });

    $(".copy").unbind().click(function() {
      let name = $(this).parent().prev().text();
      let actionsTpl = '<button class="hi">Hi</button> <button class="copy">Copy</button>';

      table.row.add([index++, name, actionsTpl]).draw();
      initRowsEvents();
    });
  }

  // Tried this event, doesn't seems to work in this case...
  $('#myTable').on('length.dt', () => initRowsEvents());


});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>
        <button class="hi">Hi</button>
        <button class="copy">Copy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching i found this examples : https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html
So the solution was to place the event on the table body on not on the row, so no need to
reinitialize it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let table = $('#myTable').DataTable({"stateSave": true});
  let index = 2;

   $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
        let name = $(this).parent().prev().text();
        let actionsTpl = '<button class="hi">Hi</button> <button class="copy">Copy</button>';
        
        if($(this).hasClass('hi'))
          alert('Oh, Hi ' + name + '!');
          
        if($(this).hasClass('copy')) {
          table.row.add([index++, name, actionsTpl]).draw();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>
        <button class="hi">Hi</button>
        <button class="copy">Copy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```